# I have reviewed my declined flag, how to remove the warning?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I recently had a mod flag declined on meta. I don't disagree with the rejection. But whenever I go to flag a question on meta I get a warning saying:

> Your recent flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

And it looks like this:

> [image]

I have clicked on 'review' and reviewed my declined flag several times but this warning doesn't leave. Is this persistence by-design or is it a bug? If it is by-design then when do I expect this warning to leave? And are there any actions that I can take to remove it?

---

I flagged rene's "thanks" comment but I still get this warning.

Comment: It's been that way for a long while, I found this [comment from 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281152/your-last-flag-was-declined-no-it-wasnt#comment914142_281152) mentioning that it keeps nagging for a long time. I thought that this was asked before and it was made intentionally invasive to ensure people got super obvious warnings before a flag ban, but I can't actually find an example question, so I may be remembering wrong.

Comment: I think it's a bug, as on main when I flag something and it's declined it only tells me once (as if I needed that, I already knew from looking at my flagging history). So it's probably a bug I think. Even it it's not, then I think it's a bad feature that needs to be removed.

Comment: "*And are there any actions that I can take to remove it?*" I think it only looks at literally the last flag you've done, so it goes away after you flag again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The warning is triggered when at least 10% of the flags you've raised, processed in the past 7 days, have been declined. Depending on how many flags you've raised, this could be as few as one flag!

from  [Why am I seeing the message "Some of your recent flags have been decline" when flagging?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223382)

So to get rid of the warning sooner raise plenty of new post flags that don't get declined. Or wait 6 to 8 days.

You might argue you would like to have some way to dismiss that message once read. There is an argument from Tim Post from not yet 6 to 8 years ago why that's unlikely to get implemented: [Shouldn't the "recent declined flags" warning go away after clicking the link to review your flag history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281395)